# Counting "lattice points" on a circle of radius $\sqrt{N}$

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-geometry, pi, characters

Many people of the online math community are familiar with this popular video, and this post refers to it: https://youtu.be/NaL_Cb42WyY ("Pi hiding in prime regularities").

In the video, $\chi (n)$ is defined as follows:
$$\chi (n) = \begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } n \equiv 1\pmod 4 \\
-1 & \mbox{if } n \equiv -1 \pmod 4\\
0& \mbox{if }n\equiv 0\pmod 2. \end{cases}$$

I understand the video, except for two things (they were not explained; the second one should have been present in the video, as it is the core of the main idea):

1) How to prove that $\chi (n_1)\chi (n_2)= \chi (n_1 n_2)$ using the above definition of $\chi$?

2) Writing down the case for general $N$ would be a bit messy, so I'll try to explain the idea using an example: How to prove that if, for example, $N=2^2 3^4 5^3$, then the number of *lattice points* on a circle with radius $\sqrt{N}$ is
$$4\sum_{n=0}^2 \chi (2^n)\sum_{n=0}^4\chi (3^n)\sum_{n=0}^3 \chi (5^n)?$$

Based on the information given in the video, is it possible to show that we can use the $\chi$ function to *count the lattice points* (i.e. why can we exploit the $\chi$ function like that)? In the video, it's been already shown how to count the lattice points (in another way, therefore not using the $\chi$ function), **but the reasoning behind the connection of the** $\chi$ **function to the number of lattice points remains obscure**.

I guess the answer to the first question should be straightforward, but it's confusing that no one in the comment section of the video asked the second question. I watched it several times and still can't figure it out.

Comment: For 1), since $n_1 n_2\pmod 4 = (n_1\pmod 4)(n_2\pmod 4)$, the equation holds.

Comment: The problem of finding the number of lattice points inside a circle is called the Gauss Circle Problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem

Comment: @Angela But where is the connection to $\chi (n)$?

Comment: @Angle Oh, I see now. It's just interpreted another way. But the approach is missing, which is what this question is all about.

Comment: With $f(n) = \sum_{a,b, a^2+b^2=n} 1$ and $\chi(2n)=0,\chi(2n+1) = (-1)^n$, the identity $f(n) =4 \sum_{d | n} \chi(d)$ follows from the factorization of prime numbers in [prime ideals of the PID $\Bbb{Z}[i]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Gaussian_primes) those being well-understood in term of the finite field extension $\Bbb{F}_p(i)/\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Your "$2)$" *was* explained in the video. It comes from the fact that $\chi$ is multiplicative: That implies $\chi (n^k)=\chi ^k(n)$. And you can prove your "$1)$" easily by noting that $\chi (2n)=0$ and $\chi (2n+1)=(-1)^{n}$.